# pac4j Does Pac4j support relayState in a dynamic way?

Tags: pac4j

Does Pac4j(for SAML Client) support relayState? So that after authentication user gets redirected to the page that he/she requested originally, which might be different every time?

How a user would be able to be navigated to their original requested URL after being successfully authenticated.
For example, user requested /abc?x=2&y=4, and after coming back from IDP login page, user lands on /abc?x=2&y=4 page. Next time user requests /xyz?n=2, they land on /xzy?n=2 page after authentication.

I see this in the logs

{"@timestamp":"2023-09-11T01:12:36.613Z","@version":"1","message":"set key: **pac4jRequestedUrl**, with value: http://cypheems/neeon?ip=10.202.135.51","logger_name":"org.pac4j.play.store.PlayCookieSessionStore","thread_name":"application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10","level":"DEBUG","level_value":10000,"application.home":"/opt/docker"}

But, then when it tries to read it, it's null:
{"@timestamp":"2023-09-11T01:12:39.873Z","@version":"1","message":"Get value: **null** for key: **pac4jRequestedUrl**","logger_name":"org.pac4j.play.store.PlayCookieSessionStore","thread_name":"application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12","level":"DEBUG","level_value":10000,"application.home":"/opt/docker"}

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by design, the requested protected URL is saved into the web session and restored after a successful authentication.